# Delete Files Inside Of Directory By Size With Cron Jobs

Tags: cron

I am trying to delete all files in a certain directory with a certain size, in this case 39 bits exactly. I know the below code will delete all files that are 0 bits.

```
find /home/.../...* -size 0 -type f -exec rm -f '{}' \;
```

So what do I need to do to make it work for 39 bit files? The below cron doesn't work.

```
find /home/.../...* -size 39 -type f -exec rm -f '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you are using rm instead of find's own delete primary?

```
find /home/.../...* -size 39c -type f -delete
```

The key to why it is not working though it that the size primary takes is parameter as a number of 512k blocks and rounds the file size up to meet that, so 39 actually means a file size between 14,337 and 19,968 bytes.  To specify the size to match in bytes you need to add a suffix of `c` (for characters).

If you must use rm though then ending the command with a `+` rather than `\;` is more efficient as it will batch matching filenames together (like using xargs) to reduce the number of times it needs to call rm.